# Clarification of algebraic "fallacies" - Methods of Mathematics by Richard Hamming

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am reading the book "Methods of Mathematics" by Richard Hamming. In one section he talks about certain fallacies in algebra to avoid. He gives a very clear example of accidentally dividing by zero, but then follows it with another example which he claims performs such a violation more subtly.

$$\frac{1}{x(x-a)}-\frac{1}{x}= \frac{a}{(x-a)}$$

Okay, I see we cannot have x equal to zero, nor can we have x equal to a. No problem here. He then presents the formula "cleared of fractions".

$$1 - (x-a) = ax $$
$$1-x+a=ax$$
$$1+a=x+ax$$
$$1+a=x(1+a)$$

No problem, I see what he did. He then continues the math to solve for x, yielding

$$ x = 1 $$

And this is where the thinking begins. So it seems that he is saying that the equation is not dependent on the value of $a$. But he says this cannot be true because the original formula is not defined for $x=1$ when $a=1$ because from the original formula we reasoned that $x$ cannot be equal to $a$.  So my questions are below:

1.) Is he claiming that he's used a fallacy to solve the equation; one that results in an incorrect statement? I don't see one.

2.) Or is it that our system of symbolic manipulation is such that given the "fractionless" form initially, we wouldn't have seen the limitation that $x$ cannot equal $a$?

3.) Can the given conditions on $x$ and $a$ be readily seen in the fractionless form?

4.) If not, how do we avoid such errors? By trying multiple forms until such constraints are apparent?

5.) Why is $x$ not able to be equal to $a$? It seems that of course we cannot divide by zero, but using a different form, e.g. the fractionless form, avoids this issue. So how can changing the form of an equation make certain solutions suddenly valid? I think it probably doesn't since they are equivalent. I must be missing something here.

He also notes that when $a=-1$, all solutions for $x$ are valid except $0$ and $-1$. So it really seems like he's saying that our solution, independent of $a$, is not correct. Where did it all fall apart?

Comment: Cancelling $(1+a)$ requires $a\ne -1$, because if it is -1, the equation is true for all permissible values of $x$

Comment: Changing the form can indeed change the set of solutions. Certain values of the variables are excluded from the domain, when there is division, square roots, logarithms etc.

Comment: @Simon Now I find that very uncomfortable. I've always felt that if, for instance, the equation represents a model of a physical system, then the inability to allow certain solutions said something about the physical model or system. But you're saying that it can be just a poorly chosen form and other forms need to be investigated. Philosophically, is this a known field of research or thought? That our system of mathematics is somehow flawed in that it can exclude solutions based on algebraic rules which are valid for the physical system?

Comment: Not poorly chosen. Just that two models of two different things may share some common solutions. The different models may have different exclusions.

Comment: @UmbQbify -Key20- Okay, so I think I see what I missed. It was the division by $(1+a)$ which required $a\neq-1$ to avoid a divide by zero situation. Hamming is saying that if you make the mistake of not noticing that, and you set $a=-1$, you get all kinds of silly things, such as nearly all values of $x$ satisfying the equation. Is that about right?

Comment: But yes, in any particular model, one should try to avoid spurious restrictions on the variables.

Comment: @Aaron, you're right. You surely can't "cancel" the term when $a=-1$ because it will be $0=0x$ which is true everytime. But here $x$ already has restrictions, so just excluding those values, all values of x will satisfy. We call this a trivial case.

Comment: @Simon I think what gets me is that I can see picking different models could get you different results. But moving symbols around an algebraic equation seems like a single model but just in different forms. So it blows my mind that what I perceive as a single model can be changed by moving symbols around. Put differently, I suppose because I was taught in school that doing all the manipulations correctly resulted in the equality being preserved I naively assumed that meant that nothing changed, not even the admitted solutions or model.

Comment: In school they ought to have taught you that those operations have some rules, such as that when dividing both sides of an equation by some unknown quantity, one must consider two cases: One in which the quantity is zero and one when it isn't. It's common for things like this to be missed in school, hence the need for Hamming's book.

Comment: Sorry - I was lazy in referring to the "hidden mistake" here. It is as Brian M. Scott explains it.

Comment: @Simon No laziness was apparent. I deeply appreciate you helping me on my long journey to being a proper mathematician.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, the original equation excludes the cases $x=0$ and $x=a$. These are not excluded by the forms obtained by clearing the fractions, so when we do that, we need to make a note that $1+a=x(1+a)$ **and** $x\ne 0$ **and** $x\ne a$. But the real problem, as noted in the comments, is that we can’t divide through by $1+a$ if $a=-1$; since we don’t know what $a$ is, we have to split the remainder of the calculation into two cases, one for $a=-1$ and one for $a\ne -1$.

- If $a=-1$, the final equation reduces to $0=0\cdot x$, which is true for all $x$, and — bearing in mind the original exclusions! — we find that $x$ can be any real number except $-1$ and $0$.
- If $a\ne -1$, we can divide through by $1+a$ to find that $x=1$. Bearing in mind the original exclusions, we see that we actually have two subcases here: if $|a|\ne 1$, the unique solution is $x=1$, and if $a=1$, there is no solution.

Comment: Thank you so much for the great explanation. So what scares me is what if I was only given the "fractionless" form? How would I have seen the exclusions for $x$? They don't seem to exist there. So even if I had been clever enough to split the remainder of the calculation into two cases for $a$, I would have failed to list the exclusions for $x$ since I would have been unaware of them. So what's the best practice? Try as many forms as possible to explore for exclusions?

Comment: @Aaron: You’re very welcome. If you were given only the fractionless form, those exclusions would not exist. The thing to understand here is that the two forms are equivalent **only where they are both defined**, and the second one is defined over a larger domain than the first. If you were given the second and not the first, you’d be working with the larger domain right from the start.

Comment: Astounding. I feel like I'm having to reprogram my brain for this one. I was taught that doing operations equally on each side of an equation preserves equality. But my mind naively inferred that maintaining equality meant that the forms were identical. So now I know that changing forms is selecting different mathematical models. Changing forms changes the entire equation. The equality of the left and right is preserved, but the actual equation may have been entirely replaced with a new one with a different domain. Is this correct?

Comment: @Aaron: It’s correct, but you should also realize that in practice the changes in domain are typically small and easy to track, as they were in this example.

Comment: Sir, if you have time I'd like to clarify something. Suppose the first equation tells Scotty which antimatter mixes won't blow up the Enterprise. So he wants to solve for $x$. He transforms the equation to the second form and retains the exclusions. He solves the equation as you have in your answer. So my question is whether the excluded values are valid or not? Did the second form just remove spurious exclusions? Or was the first form derived from the physics of the engine and the second form would not have ever been derived because it lacked the essential exclusions?

Comment: @Aaron: That would depend entirely on the physics, specifically, on which equation actually **does** model the physics. There’s no way to tell simply from the equations themselves: it’s not a mathematical question.

Answer (score 5):

The key here is to understand that:

$$\frac{1}{x(x-a)}-\frac{1}{x}=\frac{a}{x-a}$$

and

$$1-(x-a)=ax$$

are not two *forms* of the same equation: those are two  *different* equations. Claiming, in general, that they have to have the same solutions amounts to wishful thinking.

However, those equations are related to each other: because the second one has been derived from the first one by, effectively, multiplying both sides with $x(x-a)$, it follows that the second equation is *implied* by the first one. Every solution of the first equation is also a solution of the second one. The second equation is *not equivalent* to the first one because the opposite operation (dividing both sides by $x(x-a)$) is possible only if $x\ne 0,x\ne a$.

So, how to avoid confusion and mistakes? I have seen at least the following three methods:

- **Distinguish the cases**. In our case, this means having two cases: (1) $x=0$ or $x=a$, which are obvious non-solutions of the first equation, and (2) $x\ne 0, x\ne a$: in *that* case, the second equation *is* equivalent to the first, so we can proceed to solving *it* and then *restricting* the set of solutions to our case (i.e. disregarding solutions equal to $0$ or $a$).
- **Equivalent transformations**: You can directly transform the first equation into an equivalent formula, but this formula may stop being an *equation* - it may became a logical (predicate) formula. Indeed, $\frac{x}{y}=z$ is equivalent to $x=yz\land y\ne 0$, or, in our case, the first formula is equivalent to:

$$1-(x-a)=ax\land x\ne 0\land x\ne a$$

and, eventually, this transforms further into:

$$(x=1\lor a=-1)\land x\ne 0\land x\ne a$$

- **Follow the implications but check in the end**. Useful when the number of solutions is finite. In this method, we don't worry if we have transformed an equation into an *equivalent* one: it is sufficient to transform it into one *implied by* the first equation. This does mean that every subsequent equation may gain some solutions that the original equation did not have. Once you've gone all the way and solved the last equation, *go back and check* whether those solutions also satisfy the original equation. Those that do are the solutions of the original equation.

For the last method, see this example:$\sqrt{x+1}=x-1$. By squaring both sides (which again does not produce an equivalent equation, since squares of two numbers may be equal even if the numbers themselves are not), we get: $x+1=x^2-2x+1$, i.e. $x^2=3x$, i.e. $x=0\lor x=3$. However, $x=0$ is not the solution of the original equation, and $x=3$ is the only solution.

I believe that, didactically, the third method, whenever it can be used, carries the advantage that it also reinforces the good habit of checking one's work at the end.

Hope this helps.

**Edit**: Following up rigorously all the conditions (either method!) becomes even more important if you are trying to solve *inequalities*. For example, $\frac{x}{y}\lt z$ happens to be equivalent to $x\lt yz$ when $y\gt 0$, but is equivalent to $x\gt yz$ when $y\lt 0$...

Comment: Fabulous information. Thank you so much for such a detailed explanation. I must admit that this is a little disappointing for me. I'm a software engineer trying to greatly improve my math abilities and it seems like what appear to be basic mathematical facts have escaped my previous education. Just when I think I'm past "the basics" I find myself getting caught by the little things again. Thanks for your help. Great examples!

Comment: @Aaron Then you know a lot about the code that "almost works" but suffers from "edge cases" ;) A similar situation here: in school they teach you the transformations that give you quick solutions in straightforward cases, but to solve real problems you need to understand what you are *really* doing when you are applying those transformations.